# PHP digital envelope routines::unsupported"

Tags: php, openssl

My app (that previusly worked) now started failing on function

```
openssl_pkcs12_read()
```

due to

> error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Using MacOS Monterey, PHP v7.3

How do I fix this?

Comment: Upgrade PHP or downgrade openSSL

Comment: @mousetail Updated PHP to 8.1. and am still getting the same error. Updated OpenSSL to OpenSSL 1.1.1u  30 May 2023, the same errror remains